# Sql Server Migration tool not quite working

Tags: sql-server, oracle10g, sql-server-migration-assi

I was finally able to get the schema correct on both sides. Im ready to run the final step and....

Data migration started....
Data migration failed... System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 se

I have done ever suggestion on google known to man
1) install oracle client 10.2 and remove 10.1
2) add "authenticated users" to the oracle home directory
3) restart sql services
4) reboot machine

to no avail what so ever. What is the deal? help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have x64 machines as the SQL Server and/or machine running the SSMA client? You could install just x86 Oracle client but the migration tool was running as 64bit executable (it's a part of the SSMA that works on the SQL Server side through SQL Server Agent AFAIK). **If you have some x64 setups present, please try installing x64 Oracle client as well. Although make sure you have Oracle client on the server that runs target SQL Server** (during the data migration, it doesn't pump your data through SSMA client tool - it tries to connect from SQL Server machine directly to the source Oracle server).

PS: I understand it's quite too late to suggest a solution, but in case someone has something similar... And (as always) a log with appropriate verbosity level would be nice to look into too...